# I want to copy data from one workbook to another if two columns has same value in both workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to copy data from one workbook to another if two columns have the same value in both workbooks (if column A and B has the same value in both workbooks then copy and paste column C & D)

I had applied below code but it is giving "subscript out of range" error in first loop

```
Sub transfer()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim companyname As String
Dim activistname As String


Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\PrathameshA\Desktop\final_eventsdata.csv"
Sheets("final_eventsdata").Activate

lastrow1 = Sheets("final_eventsdata").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow1

            companyname = Sheets("final_eventsdata").Cells(i, "B").Value
            activistname = Sheets("final_eventsdata").Cells(i, "I").Value
            
            Workbooks("Live_Macro").Activate
            Worksheets("Live").Activate
            lastrow2 = Sheets("Live").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 2 To lastrow2

If Sheets("Live").Cells(j, "A").Value = companyname And Sheets("Live").Cells(j, "B").Value = activistname Then

            Workbooks("final_eventsdata").Activate
            Sheets("final_eventsdata").Activate
            Sheets("final_eventsdata").Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "F")).Copy
            Workbooks("Live_Macro").Activate
            Sheets("Live").Activate
            Sheets("Live").Range(Cells(j, "C"), Cells(j, "F")).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
    
End If

Next j

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next i

Sheets("Live").Activate
Sheets("Live").Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Pratham .. [If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%20To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A%20%201%20Choose,un-accept%20the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.%20More%20)

Answer (score 0):

When working with multiple workbooks you should make sure to include workbook references when referring to objects, e.g. worksheets, in those workbooks.

You should also avoid switching between workbooks/worksheets using Activate, that's not needed and can cause problems.

A good idea when running this sort of code is to create variables that reference the particular workbooks/sheets etc. involved, that's what I've not in the first few lines of the following code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub transfer()
Dim wbEvents As Workbook
Dim wsEvents As Worksheet
Dim wbLive As Workbook
Dim wsLive As Worksheet
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim rngSrc As Range
Dim companyname As String
Dim activistname As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long

    Set wbLive = Workbooks("Live Macro")
    Set wsLive = wbLive.Sheets("Live")

    Set wbEvents = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\PrathameshA\Desktop\final_eventsdata.csv")
    Set wsEvents = wbEvents.Sheets(1)

    lastrow1 = wsEvents.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow1

        companyname = wsEvents.Cells(i, "B").Value
        activistname = wsEvents.Cells(i, "I").Value

        lastrow2 = wsLive.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For j = 2 To lastrow2

            If wsLive.Cells(j, "A").Value = companyname And wsLive.Cells(j, "B").Value = activistname Then
                With wsEvents
                    Set rngSrc = .Range(.Cells(i, "C"), .Cells(i, "F"))
                End With

                With wsLive
                    Set rngDst = .Range(.Cells(j, "C"), .Cells(j, "F"))
                End With

                rngSrc.Copy rngDst
            End If

        Next j

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank y0u Sir, it was really helpfull